# How to use download picture in WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I want to download a jpg, and use it in my game.

This is my code, and this code works very well in unity Editor and unity web player. But when I build a WebGL, it just show a picture with a "?". Is there something wrong?

This the "?" picture
[image]

```
IEnumerator TestDownPNG() {
    string url = "https://xxxx/test_bg.jpg";
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    Texture2D texture2d = www.textureNonReadable;
    Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create (texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, texture2d.width, texture2d.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));

    objectA.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
}
```

Comment: Have just tried, works for me in WebGL. Are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I find a error " XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxx/test.jpg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51658' is therefore not allowed access.". And then post my WebGL to a server, it works. Thanks.